# what is this "CONSTANT>>1" in c++\msdn

Tags: c++, constants, msdn

I'm working on a code given to me by my cousin.
In the code there is a symbol that I don't recognize.
It would be awesome if anyone can help recognize and explain it to me!

OBJECT_SIZE is a constant
">> 1" the part I need help understanding.

"OBJECT_SIZE>>1"

```
    m_CenterPt    = Point2F(middle.x - (OBJECT_SIZE>>1) - MIDOFFSET,
                            middle.y - (OBJECT_SIZE>>1) - MIDOFFSET);
```

Comment: It's a misguided way of writing `OBJECT_SIZE/2`.

Comment: Right shift , each right shift means divide by `2` !

Comment: of course that is under the assumption (makes 100% sense) that OBJECT_SIZE is unsigned (and or holds a positive value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `>>` operator is a shift right; shifting a positive number right by one bit is equivalent to integer-dividing by two (for the same reason why removing the last digit of a decimal number is an equivalent of integer-dividing the number by ten).

Comment: wow, you have a great way of explaining things. Thanks dasblinkenlight!